# How to align check-box to the right in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have below `shiny-app`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style = "height: 20px; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.0); margin-top: 15px;
                            display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;", 
                tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#Div_Holder.form-group.shiny-input-container {
                                                    width: 10px;
                                                }
                                            "
                                            ))),


                div(style = "margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: auto; min-width: 10px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4); margin-right: 15px;", 
                    HTML("Name")),
                div(id = "Div_Holder", style = "margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: auto; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8); margin-right: 15px;
                                display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;", 
                    shinyWidgets::prettyCheckbox("Chose", label = NULL))
            )
)
server <- function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you see, the `checkbox` is not completely aligned to the right. I tried to modify the class `form-group.shiny-input-container`, but was not successful.

Any pointer towards the right approach will be highly appreciated.